# Show net gain/loss for particular stock

Tags: gnucash, capital-gain

For a particular stock that has been bought and sold a few times, is there a way to view the net gain or loss, rather than the piece-meal capital gains or losses? I found that only the current net shares of stock are tallied in either "Accounts" or "View Lots," rather than an up-to-date gain or loss for all transactions.

Addendum: I meant to say this question was for the stock accounting application, GnuCash. Sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 1):

My broker's end-of-month and end-of-year statements provide the capital gain total per security.  Check to see if yours does.  If so, add the capital gain for open positions and you have the total.

If your broker doesn't offer this then place all closed trades in a spreadsheet, sort by security and determine the sum per security. Then add the capital gain for open positions and you have the total.

Answer (score 1):

The *Advanced Portfolio* report show a breakdown of the realized gains, unrealized gains, income and overall gain for each account holding shares. It is found under *Assets & Liabilities* in the *Reports* menu.

The report options allow you to select the accounts you want to include  and the basis calculation method, among other things.